# Is it possible to post on an event feed on behalf of the user?

Tags: events, facebook-graph-api, post, feed, facebook-php-sdk

Here's the scenario: 
The user has set that is attending an event, I want through my app (php sdk) to post on that event's feed on behalf of the particular user. I already have publish_stream extended permission from the user.

The post might happen at a later stage while the user is offline (but from what I understand offline permission is now depreacated).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can post [`link`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/link/), [`post`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/post/) or [`status message`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/status/) to Event feed via Graph API, you should issue `POST` request to [`feed`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/#feed) connection of [`event`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/event/)

This is an example for publishing `link`:

```
POST https://graph.facebook.com/EVENT_ID/feed?link=http://example.com&access_token=...
```

As you noticed `offline_access` permission is deprecated (and will stop working May 1, 2012, see [Developer Roadmap](https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/)) you should read [how to handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/) and how to [extend token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/offline-access-deprecation/).

Comment: thanks. seems like my problem was that my access tokens expired and they cannot be extended for users who already went through the permissions dialog. not sure if it is by design but only users who deauthorize the app and reauthorize it now that i changed the deprecate offline_access setting receive an extended token.